# Tengo una interfaz grafica con tkinter en python3 y quiero llenar el campo text con mensajes que se generan en el cuerpo de una funcion

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo este codigo con una interfaz grafica donde se indica un valor entero y ejecuta una funcion al presionar el boton "Ejecutar Calculo".

El el campo texto inserta el resultado de cada operacion indicada en el "bucle for", pero se ve en pantalla solo cuando la funcion termina y no se va insertando a medida que se ejecuta cada paso dentro de la funcion tal como se ve en la terminal con la funcion "print"

La intencion es hacer un log con la ejecución el proceso completo

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Menu Principal')

valor_rango = int()

def calcular():
    global valor_rango
    
    valor_rango = int(rango.get())
    
    for x in range(valor_rango):
        log_avance.config(state='normal')
        log_avance.insert(tk.INSERT, 'El resultado es ')
        log_avance.insert(tk.INSERT, x * 2)
        log_avance.insert(tk.INSERT, '\n')
        log_avance.config(state='disable')
    

my_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=700, height=600)
my_frame.pack()


rango = tk.Entry(my_frame)
rango.grid(row=0, column=1)
rango_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text='Rango de numeros')
rango_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e', pady=10, padx=10)


log_avance = tk.Text(my_frame, width=30, height=10)
log_avance.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan=4)
log_avance_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text='Log de Ejecucion')
log_avance_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
log_avance.config(state='disable')

ejecutar = tk.Button(my_frame, text='Ejecutar Calculo', command=calcular)
ejecutar.grid(row=7, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Humberto, ejecuté tu código y veo que corre sin problemas (con unas modificaciones al código que hice pero sin alterar su naturaleza), pero podrías explicar mejor lo que deseas para poder ayudarte? la función se ejecuta correctamente

Comment: si el codigo funciona pero las lineas se agregan al cuadro text solo cuando la funcion se temina de ejecutar y no en cada paso, si usas un valo alto ej 5.000 toda la info aparece de una vez y lo que quiero es que vayan apareciendo linea a linea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes colocar dentro del `for` lo siguiente:

```
root.update_idletasks()
```

Con esto actualizamos la ventana con cada tarea que ejecutemos..

Tu código quedaría así (con algunos cambios que hice):

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Menu Principal')


def calcular(valor_rango):
    
    rango.delete(0,'end')
    log_avance.config(state='normal')
       
    for x in range(valor_rango):
        log_avance.insert(tk.END, 'El resultado es ' + str(x * 2) + '\n')
        root.update_idletasks()
        sleep(1)
    log_avance.config(state='disable')
    

my_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=700, height=600)
my_frame.pack()


rango = tk.Entry(my_frame)
rango.grid(row=0, column=1)
rango_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text='Rango de numeros')
rango_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e', pady=10, padx=10)


log_avance = tk.Text(my_frame, width=30, height=10)
log_avance.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan=4)
log_avance_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text='Log de Ejecucion')
log_avance_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
log_avance.config(state='disable')

ejecutar = tk.Button(my_frame, text='Ejecutar Calculo', command=lambda:calcular(int(rango.get())))
ejecutar.grid(row=7, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Los cambios que hice:

- Eliminé la variable global `valor_rango` y la coloqué como argumento de la función y desde el comando del botón con la función `lambda` le pasamos el valor `rango.get()` como argumento a la función calcular

> ```
> def calcular(valor_rango):
> ejecutar = tk.Button(my_frame, text='Ejecutar Calculo',command=lambda:calcular(int(rango.get())))
> ```

- Importé el módulo `time` para usar la función `sleep` solo con la finalidad de que puedas ver el resultado por segundos

> ```
> from time import sleep
>
> sleep(1)  # colocado dentro del for y entre paréntesis los segundos
> ```

- El `rango.delete(0,'end')` solo lo coloqué para limpiar el Entry al presionar el botón de cálculo